# Connecting to a database with Ruby on shared hosting without ssh

Tags: ruby, database

So, I'm learning Ruby and I'm trying to write a simple Sinatra app. Problem is, from what I'm gathering there's no database drivers included with Ruby and I can't install the MySQL driver that I found without ssh. Is there another option?

Comment: Sure, but you'd have to tell us more about your environment.

Comment: Just a cheap hosting with FastCGI. I can run Sinatra with no problems at all. Is there some gem that I can 'require' locally (like I'm doing with Sinatra and its dependencies) to connect to MySQL/Postgres?

Comment: what exactly depends on ssh? I _think_ that mysql will only care about having access to the standard mysql port, 3600? Or do you mean you can't install it without ssh?

Comment: Have you tried using bundler? http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2009/using-the-rubygems-bundler-for-your-app/

Answer (score 0):

I presume from your question that you cannot install the mysql gem because you don't have ssh access, and hence can't run gem install mysql from the command line? If so, presumably you're uploading your application via FTP or similar?

If so, one possible approach would be to cross-compile the mysql native extension on your home machine, for the target architecture of your host, and then vendor the mysql gem into your application before uploading it to your host. As an alternative, it might be possible to find pre-built native extensions (although I haven't looked for any).

Needless to say, this is a pretty round-about and involved route. A better option would be to find a shared host that supported Rails/Sinatra better. I have found site5.com to be excellent and competitive, but I'm sure that there are others.